# How can I keep value the same after closing the program? VB.net

Tags: vb.net

A Test score is stored and written into a text file with other user's scores and stored in a variable.

Within the program is a score form which displays the scores from all the tests for that user in the Progress form. It works after I have completed the test, but when I log out and close the program it goes back to 0 in the label.

However when I close the program and then re-run the program, the values change back to 0 and not the actual test score written to the text file.

How would I make it so that the values are kept the same when I run the program for that user?

End Sub Module was created to store Public variables `Public Topic1Score As Integer`

This is a code extract from the test itself

```
If answers(i) = questions(i, 4) And FileOpenStatusTS = False Then
    Topic1Score += 1
    TotalScore += 1
End If
Next

If yearst = "12" And classst = "A" Then
    FileOpen(1, FileName12A1, OpenMode.Append)
    FileOpenStatus12A1 = True`
```

Once all the details have been entered and checked, then they are written to the Teacher accounts text file

```
WriteLine(1, Username, Topic1Score, TotalScore)
FileClose(1)
End If
```

Here is the reading of the file within the progress form.

```
Private Sub StProgress_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Debug.Assert(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Topic1Score))
    lblTotalScore.Text = TotalScore

    LblTopic2Score.Text = "You scored " & Topic2Score & " out of 5"

    lblStName.Text = namest
    LblStSurname.Text = surnamest


    If yearst = "12" And classst = "A" Then
        Dim Filefound As Boolean
        Filefound = False
        FileOpen(1, FileName12A1, OpenMode.Input)
        While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False


            Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
            Input(1, Topic1Score)
            Input(1, TotalScore)
            Filefound = True
            lblTopic1Score.Text = "You scored " & Topic1Score & " out of 5"
        End While
    End If

    If yearst = "13" And classst = "A" Then
        Dim Filefound As Boolean
        Filefound = False
        FileOpen(1, FileName13A1, OpenMode.Input)
        While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False


            Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
            Input(1, Topic1Score)
            Input(1, TotalScore)
            Filefound = True
            lblTopic1Score.Text = "You scored " & Topic1Score & " out of 5"
        End While
    End If
    If yearst = "12" And classst = "B" Then
        Dim Filefound As Boolean
        Filefound = False
        FileOpen(1, FileName12B1, OpenMode.Input)
        While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False
            Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
            Input(1, Topic1Score)
            Input(1, TotalScore)
            Filefound = True
            lblTopic1Score.Text = "You scored " & Topic1Score & " out of 5"
        End While
    End If
    If yearst = "13" And classst = "B" Then
        Dim Filefound As Boolean
        Filefound = False
        FileOpen(1, FileName13B1, OpenMode.Input)
        While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False


            Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
            Input(1, Topic1Score)
            Input(1, TotalScore)
            Filefound = True
            lblTopic1Score.Text = "You scored " & Topic1Score & " out of 5"
        End While
    End If
End Sub`
```

Latest Code...
Code within test...
` FileOpenStatusT = False
        Dim Filefound As Boolean
        Filefound = False
        FileOpen(1, Filenamet, OpenMode.Input)
        While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False
            Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the TeacherAccounts text file'
            Input(1, Password)
            Input(1, namet)
            Input(1, surnamet)

```
        If Username = TxtUsername.Text And Password = TxtPassword.Text Then 'If the username and account entered are valid then the user is navigated to the TeacherMenu form'
            Filefound = True
            t = Username
        End If
    End While

    If Filefound = False Then
        MsgBox("Username and Password were not a match,please try again")
    Else
        TeacherMenu.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If`
```

progress form code...
 If yearst = "12" And classst = "A" Then
            Dim Filefound As Boolean
            Filefound = False
            FileOpen(1, FileName12A1, OpenMode.Input)
            While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False

```
            Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
            Input(1, Topic1Score)
            Input(1, TotalScore)
            Filefound = True
            If Username = t Then
                lblTopic1Score.Text = "You scored " & Topic1Score & " out of 5"
            End If
```

t is a string and set as a public variable in a module.

Comment: Please show us your code.  There's no way to guess at what is happening.

Comment: I have re-edited the code

Comment: The code for the content reading is the same - I recommend you to change the file name in a "case" or "if" but to use the same reading code.

Comment: Please don't use ``Code``. Just indent your code by 4 spaces. You can select the code then use Control-K.

Answer (score 4):

there are 3 different options for you:

1. Use the file system, and create a file for it (requires some work).
   If I understand correctly - that's what you did, and you have a bug in it... for getting help with debugging it - post the code.
   I think the problem in your code is that you're opening the file in append mode.
   You didn't post the read of the file, but I guess you read the first score there, but instead of writing over it everytime - you write at the end of the file.
   so your file probably looks like that:
   0
   1
   2
   and you always read the 0...
   if this is not the problem - post the read too.
2. Use the registry to hold the variable (requires less work).
3. Use the user area app.config to store this data.
   This area, in contradiction to the app area, can be modified by the application, and will be retained for each user separately.

I think the third is the easiest and fastest.
good luck

---

So I think the problem is that in the file read you don't "narrow down" the relevant user.

In this code:

```
   Dim Filefound As Boolean
    Filefound = False
    FileOpen(1, FileName12B1, OpenMode.Input)
    While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False
        Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
        Input(1, Topic1Score)
        Input(1, TotalScore)
        Filefound = True
-------IF THE Username == t here... - the currently logged in user ... run the following line
        lblTopic1Score.Text = "You scored " & Topic1Score & " out of 5"
-------IF the Username == the currently logged in user - break the loop
------- UNLESS - the last student record is necessary, since the grades were written in append mode

    End While
```

That should solve the issue.

Is it a practice system, or a "real" system? 
I'm asking since it is not secure to allow access from the end client to the file that holds the user data... for practicing it is OK, but for a real system you need to change the architecture.

Comment: Posted the code that involved the variable Topic1Score

Comment: Do you have only one user in each file?

Comment: No Each class E.g 12A1 has a text file for all their scores in, so that a Teacher can log in and read the text file for each class and the test they took.

Comment: But you have one label there that you're over-writing in each cycle, so the last student is being presented ... you should implement something to pick the student you want to display

Comment: This form is for the Student Login, I just mentioned the Teacher Log in to explain it. This is just for the student who took the tests or previously took the tests can see what there scores are.

Comment: but the file has the content for all the students, so there should be "if (username = ...)" somewhere.. (am I missing something? I feel I'm missing your point..)

Comment: I just want it so that everytime a Student logs in , they can click on the form and it will display all their scores of the tests they have completed in the labels.

But how would I make it so that it reads and displays the user's score and not anyone elses? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: When you load the form - How do you know which score to display? (this was my point) - from this code I think that you read all the students grades, one by one, and change them within the same spot - so you always display the last grade that appears in the file, without any relation to the student that uses the app.

Comment: Right so I think I get you, but how do I fix it so that when the form loads the right username's scores are displayed. I don't know how to do 2 and 3 like you suggested.

Comment: Its for my Computing coursework, all I have left to do is this, so its not a real system. Surely if I did how you say, then I would have to write than multiple times with all the different usernames? but then once a new Username is created I would have to manually write it again

Comment: I don't understand what you meant. So you have a system that can be in either "teacher" mode or a "student" mode - if it is in a student mode, you have the "current student" so you just need to feed it to the method, so the "if" will know which user to return. If you are in a teacher mode - you need a different screen to display multiple students grades, or to ask the teacher to use a specific user, which than acts the same as in the "student mode". what am I missing?

Comment: I have the Teacher login, which a selection screen for the year then the classes then in that form it displays the text files in a listbox. In the student one I don't get your edited version or how I would do the Username = currently logged on user to display the score? Sorry for being an idiot, you don't have to help me.

Comment: You need to have a variable that says you which the currently user that is using the system / the current user the teacher is looking at. you can do it in multiple ways - between a static variable to more local way, this is your decision to take - but you have to know which user to show, when you know which user to show - just use the variable that holds it in the if.

Comment: and btw - don't feel bad - it's all part of the learning process.

Comment: I get the logic behind it and understand you, but I have no clue how I would go about completing it. Could I not do it through some kind of search of the Username?.

Comment: No, unless you hold the grades for each student in a different file, you'll have to search the one file that has all the users for the right one... Have lunch, think of it, and comment after thinking on what changes you need to do to your code for knowing it.. I think a break from it will help you (it usually helps me..)

Comment: I was thinking surely I could do it similiar to how your were saying with a variable, where I created a variable `Public t As String` that when you log in that variable is the username, then when reading the file I put the code input `(t,Username, Topic1Score, TotalScore)` however it didn't work. Any last help you can provide ?

Comment: It couldn't not work...  :) if it didn't work - you should have got left with an empty fields on the view (since the if will match either the last student score record or none - if the user don't have any scores). can you debug this loop, and see when it gets into the label.text code and what are the values of t and the Username? they have to match..

Comment: I just logged in and went straight to the progress screen and it worked then i closed it and re-logged in then it gave me the same error as before [Link]http://i1372.photobucket.com/albums/ag336/fxjosh/CodeError_zps6146f124.jpg[Link]

Comment: so WriteLine takes a file# (probably 1 in your case), not a string.. The user search should be after reading the content from the file, not while reading it.

Comment: wait so I should keep the t = Username bit in the login, then change the `Input (t, Username...)` back to `Input (1, Username...) but then how would I write the code for the search?

Comment: Added the place for the t in the above relevant if.

Comment: I edited the code if you want to look at the bottom for one last time,  I won't bother you again.

Comment: Can you use  Debug.WriteLine(Username); Debug.Writeline(t); and see what it sees? (or set a breakpoint there - and check in each iteration what's the values of Username and t , and why they're not matching)?

Comment: I posted it again with just the recent code, it may be clearer for you on there [Link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850912/labels-for-scores-in-a-test-system-are-not-showing-the-scores-for-vb-net[Link]

Comment: I put Debug.WriteLine(Username); Debug.Writeline(t) below where I put the other debug, but I don't know what to do next as I haven't used these before.

Comment: Debug will print in the VS environment (usually on the bottom right) whatever you print.. So you could see what is being considered on run time