# How do I get the Labels to display the current user's scores from the tests in the labels?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a Test system that is supposed to show the scores in the labels, however when run the labels stay as the default set text of "Test Not yet completed"

The variable t is created public in a module `Public t As String`

This is the code when the user logs in and the variable t is set to the username of the current user.

```
FileOpenStatusst = False
Dim Filefound As Boolean
Filefound = False
FileOpen(1, FileNamest, OpenMode.Input)
While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False
  Input(1, Username)
  Input(1, Password)
  Input(1, namest)
  Input(1, surnamest)
  Input(1, classst)
  Input(1, yearst)
  If Username = TxtUsername.Text And Password = TxtPassword.Text Then
    Filefound = True
    t = Username
  End If
End While
If Filefound = False Then
  MsgBox("Username and Password were not a match,please try again")
Else
  StudentMenu.Show()
  Me.Hide()
End If
FileClose(1)
```

This is the code for the Progress Screen to show the Test Score in the label

```
Private Sub StProgress_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Debug.Assert(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Topic1Score))
  lblStName.Text = namest
  LblStSurname.Text = surnamest

  If yearst = "12" And classst = "A" Then
    Dim Filefound As Boolean
    Filefound = False
    FileOpen(1, FileName12A1, OpenMode.Input)
    While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False
      Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
      Input(1, Topic1Score)
      Input(1, TotalScore)
      Filefound = True
      If Username = t Then
        lblTopic1Score.Text = "You scored " & Topic1Score & " out of 5"
      End If
      FileClose()
      Dim Filefound2 As Boolean
      Filefound2 = False
      FileOpen(1, FileNameTotalScores, OpenMode.Input)
      While Not EOF(1) And Filefound2 = False
        Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
        Input(1, TotalScore)
        Filefound = True
        If Username = t Then
          lblTotalScore.Text = "Your current Total Score is " & TotalScore
        End If
      End While
    End While
  End If
```

Here is the code for the when the user completes the test and the score is added up then stored.

FileClose(1)
        FileOpenStatusTS = False

```
    For i = 0 To 4

        If answers(i) = questions(i, 4) And FileOpenStatusTS = False Then

            Topic1Score += 1
            TotalScore += 1
            TestsCompleted += 1
            Attempts += 1



        End If

    Next
    Topic1Score.ToString()
    If yearst = "12" And classst = "A" Then
        FileOpen(1, FileName12A1, OpenMode.Append)
        FileOpenStatus12A1 = True

        'Once all the details have been entered and checked, then they are written to the Teacher accounts text file'
        WriteLine(1, Username, Topic1Score, Attempts)
        FileClose(1)
    End If
```

Comment: Does the user succeed in logging in? or does this code fails too?

Comment: The user can log in fine and load the progress form, its there where the Total Score and Topic Score labels are the default text.

Comment: And your question is?..

Comment: Can you open the files and see that everything is in the right format?

Comment: How do I get the Labels to display the current user's scores from the tests in the labels? Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: When I access the files they are in the same format as coded E.g Username "bob" Scored "4" Attempts "1"

Comment: I have added the Test Completion code

Comment: btw - why the second while is within the first one? it looks like it shouldn't be, and after the End While of it. (it is not correctness issue, but performance one)

Comment: it actually is a matter of correctness.. you are accidentally using the same file ID...

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that you're writing 3 variables to the file, and reading only two.

The run time cannot guess that there's another variable on the way.

Add

```
Input(1, Topic1Score)
```

in the while loop between the two inputs that are already there (or in the relevant place if I did not figure out the format correctly)..

it should look like that:

```
  While Not EOF(1) And Filefound2 = False
    Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
    Input(1, Topic1Score)
    Input(1, TotalScore)
    Filefound = True
    If Username = t Then
      lblTotalScore.Text = "Your current Total Score is " & TotalScore
    End If
  End While
```

The file format is the same for each record  - so you need to read the same way the first record, and the rest of them.

---

Please separate the loops too (you use the same file ID, so the reads are "confused"):

```
 If yearst = "12" And classst = "A" Then
    Dim Filefound As Boolean
    Filefound = False
    FileOpen(1, FileName12A1, OpenMode.Input)
    While Not EOF(1) And Filefound = False
      Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
      Input(1, Topic1Score)
      Input(1, TotalScore)
      Filefound = True
      If Username = t Then
        lblTopic1Score.Text = "You scored " & Topic1Score & " out of 5"
      End If
    End While

    FileClose()
    Dim Filefound2 As Boolean
    Filefound2 = False
    FileOpen(1, FileNameTotalScores, OpenMode.Input)
    While Not EOF(1) And Filefound2 = False
      Input(1, Username) 'All the details are read from that account from the 12A1 text file'
      Input(1, TotalScore)
      Filefound = True
      If Username = t Then
        lblTotalScore.Text = "Your current Total Score is " & TotalScore
      End If
    End While
  End If
```

Comment: This is what I did...
http://i1372.photobucket.com/albums/ag336/fxjosh/ThisIsWhatIdid_zpsf1957e93.jpg[Link]

This is what I got...
http://i1372.photobucket.com/albums/ag336/fxjosh/ProgressAndScoreslabelError_zpsf50e73da.jpg[Link]

Comment: That is the design of my Progress form with the labels in. I am still confused of where you mean sorry, could you show me by putting some of the code in, like you did before.

Comment: Sorry had some of the code wrong I have changed the inputs to what they need to be and still doesn't work, The TotalScore variable is not stored in the Student's text file ( first inputs ) so it wouldnt be needed. http://i1372.photobucket.com/albums/ag336/fxjosh/HadCodeWrong_zps8e648668.jpg[Link]